# using yq to base64 encode k8s secret values

Tags: bash, jq, kubernetes, yaml

I have a simple secret.yaml file:

```
env:
  USERNAME: user
  PASSWORD: pass
```

i'm trying to use yq / jq to encode the values for creating k8s secret, so my final result should be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-service
type: Opaque
data:
   USERNAME: <base64 encoded>
   PASSWORD: <base64 encoded>
```

i was trying to use:

```
yq r secret.yaml ".env" -j | jq -r ' to_entries[] | "\(.value)" | @base64'"
```

which gave me the base64 encoded values, but i'm failing to insert the encoded values to the final output.

i'm trying to avoid using loops but if i won't find a clean solution i'll use it.

please assist.

Comment: Your final output seems to contain much more information than what's available in the input data. Is all that extra information static?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, i intend to use static file with the new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jq` expression you'd want to apply to the data is

```
.env |= map_values(@base64) | { data: .env }
```

This updates all values of the top-level `env` structure so that they are base64-encoded. It then "renames" the `env` key to `data`.

With the particular `yq` utility that you seem to be using in the question, this is done through converting the YAML into JSON, applying `jq` to the generated JSON, and then converting it back to YAML:

```
$ yq -j r file.yml | jq '.env |= map_values(@base64) | { data: .env }' | yq -P r -
data:
  PASSWORD: cGFzcw==
  USERNAME: dXNlcg==
```

With the `yq` utility from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ (i.e., not the one that is used in the question), this is done neater using

```
$ yq -y '.env |= map_values(@base64) | { data: .env }' file.yml
data:
  USERNAME: dXNlcg==
  PASSWORD: cGFzcw==
```

Adding the extra static data could be done after running the above processing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that instead of setting a base64-encoded value in your Secrets `.data['key']`, you could pass the decoded value to `.stringData['key']`.

If I create a Secret with:

```
stringData:
  USERNAME: user
  PASSWORD: pass
```

The resulting object (what you would get using `kubectl get secret -o yaml`) would actually include:

```
data:
  USERNAME: dXNlcg==
  PASSWORD: cGFzcw==
```